# Passing Location details to mysql stored procedure

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, spatial

I have a table to stored the location details. I need to pass the latitude and longitude details to a stored procedure...

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `MOBL_Test`(IN `id` GEOMETRY)
BEGIN

insert into test_table (location) values (id) ;


END
```

how i pass value to this procedure...

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL JDBC driver does not support the `GEOMETRY` data type, so you have to use [`GeomFromText`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/populating-spatial-columns.html) in the SQL statement passed to the JDBC driver.

Comment: Well, make up your mind. Do you want it to take a *single* `GEOMETRY` parameter, or *two* parameters called `latitude` and `longitude`?

Comment: which is the best practice ?

Comment: No idea. Since JDBC has no concept of `GEOMETRY`, making your `MySQL API` (your stores procedures) use only "standard" types will allow easier use from JDBC, but since you're also writing the SQL that JDBC uses to make the stored procedure call, it's entirely up to you.

Comment: Ok.. i am passing the latitude and longitude as varchar to the stored procedure and saving to the geometry column..

    SET POINT = CONCAT('POINT(',lng,' ', lat,')');
    insert into test_table (location) values (GeomFromText(POINT));

Comment: Since the two values are numbers, I'd probably have gone with `double` or `decimal`, but `varchar` works too.